# Caching REST API (JAX-RS)

Tags: java, rest, http, caching

I want to improve performance in my REST API, I have been reading about HTTP caching but I think that don't understand the concept. If I have this resource:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response test() {
        Car car = new Car();
        car.setName("Just a car");

        CacheControl cc = new CacheControl();
        cc.setMaxAge(86400);

        Response.ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok(car);
        builder.cacheControl(cc);
        return builder.build();
    }
```

What does it exactly mean? Does it mean that the petition won't be performed again until max age is reached? Or have I to handle Cache-Control header manually in the client? I'm confused, help me to understand it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to improve performance of REST api response timings :

1. if the api is being used by multiple different client the cache-control would not help. instead use caching framework which actually cache the response to send. say by using memcache or in-memory cache or file cache.
2. if wants to improve performance such that one client need not to hit the api again to avoid network calls. then cache-control headers is being used in client side with httpCaching. Also CDN's serves the caching purpose which off-loads the server to get a request.

Comment: I'm going to test with Ehcache. Do you thing is a good choice? Would you recommend me any other in-memory cache framework?

Comment: ehcache is good when you have one server. and its good as the data could be in jvm itself so retrieval is fast. in distributed environment , ehcache would'nt help a lot, then memcache is the best to use.

Comment: Then, I will use ehcache since I have just one server and it is not worth using a server-based cache framework. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try with this api [jcabi](http://aspects.jcabi.com/annotation-cacheable.html)

You dont have to implement any caching logic , just annotation will do the magic and you can use it at any level like controller or service or dao.

Comment: Thanks! It seems a very clean way.